# Sony FDR-X3000 4K live video stream frame dropping

Tags: sony, sony-lifelog-api

I'm recently developing Sony FDR-X3000 4K Action Camera, the SDK downloaded from https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/. I found live video stream frame dropping when live mode. I used the official demo app and official app(iOS&Android) them both has the issue.

For this issue, how to resolve? Does anybody have the solutions?

Comment: "used offical demo app and offical app(iOS&Android) them both has the issue." --- contact their support then?

Comment: contacted, waitting for the response.

Comment: Sorry to hear that you are having trouble with your live stream. Have you tried using the "L" or "M" liveView size parameters by using the "startLiveviewWithsize" option? It might also be a good idea to try the "getAvailableLiveviewSize" option to see what liveview parameters are available.

Comment: Thanks:) I had tried.Above listed apis is not supported in this camera. I tested iPhone 6/6plus, 6s/6splus and 7, only iPhone 6s have the issue, Android devices also have this problem, part of devices have the issue, this is very strange.  Running the normal devices have the issue, most times is ok, once in a while have the issue, but is not serious.